# Generation of a basis of an infinite dimensional space using a finite number of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hamel-basis

Suppose the set $\mathscr{H} = \{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is a complete orthogonal set (of functions) with a given inner product operation. Let $\mathscr{H}_N = \{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$, i.e. the first $N$ elements composing the set $\mathscr{H}$.

I'm wondering under which conditions I can find a mapping $\Gamma:\mathscr{H}_N \rightarrow \mathscr{H}$ (of course nonlinear) such that **I can generate every element** of the set $\mathscr{H}$.

In other words, I would like to know under which conditions I can find a mapping such that, after its application to the finite number of (linearly independent) elements of $\mathscr{H}_N$, I can generate every $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is purely a question about cardinality and has nothing to do with inner products and orthonormality.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for your comment. I was just describing my case, and I wasn't sure if the inner products and orthonormality conditions play any role in the mapping I'm looking for.

Comment: If you want continuous: Never. If you don't have any restriction on $\Gamma$, then as long as $N≥1$.

Comment: @s.harp Thanks for the comment. I think I've a counter example to your first claim. Suppose we consider the set $\{\cos(\omega_0 t), \sin(\omega_0 t)\}\subset L^2([0,\tfrac{2\pi}{\omega_0}])$. One can always obtain a basis of $L^2([0,\tfrac{2\pi}{\omega_0}])$ with (an infinite number of) powers of $\cos(\omega_0 t), \sin(\omega_0 t)$, i.e. generation of harmonics, and the mapping is continuous. Am I right? Thanks again.

Comment: Ok, so I misunderstood the question. I thought that $\mathscr H_N$ was supposed to be the _span_ of the basis and $\mathscr H$ the original Hilbert space. In this case considering continuity doesn't make sense and the answer is always: Never. In your comment you have misunderstood the situation as you wrote it above. $\{\cos(\omega_0 t), \sin(\omega_0 t)\}$ is a set consisting of _two_ elements. Any function on it will have an image consisting either of _one_ or _two_ elements. It is impossible for you to get the entire basis like this.

Comment: @s.harp You are totally right, and I've actually posted the wrong question. Please, if you don't mind, I've just edited the original question.

Comment: What does generate mean in this context?

Comment: @s.harp "generate" as "obtain", i.e. obtain every element of the set.

Comment: That is still a meaningless phrase without a proper definition of what you are looking for!

Comment: You are looking a for mapping from a set of size $N$ into a set of size $\aleph_0$. The image of that mapping cannot have more than $N$ elements. Thus $\mathscr H_N \cup \Gamma(\mathscr H_N)$ cannot have more than $2N$ elements. That is not going to generate all of $\scr H$.